# Minecraft Launcher crashes with setUnlocalizedName(); but IntelliJ does fine

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm writing a little mod adding only one item. For this, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.1.1.

When I start the mod using IntelliJ, it works fine. When I try using the mod as a jar in a modpack, it crashes while loading, throwing a `MethodDoesNotExistError` for `setUnlocalizedName();`. Does anyone know why this happens?

I have already rewritten the entire file, but it still doesn't work. It also seems weird to me that IntelliJ does fine, but default Minecraft doesn't.

Win 10 Home Edition, IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1.1, Minecraft 1.12.2, latest 1.12.2 Forge version

Comment: Are you running the same forge version in your game as you are in IDEA? it sounds like you're using newer stuff to compile than the client has access to

Comment: Are you using gradle to build the jar, or are you using IntelliJ's build command?